# Jquery active class to menu not working

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add active class in menu link, it is working when I click on link but after loading page active class not working.I have checked it by onclick="return false". After used that active mode working fine, but here link will not work.Here is my dynamic link by php

```
<div class="list-group">

    <?php $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC limit 10",$connection);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                    ?>
            <a href="index.php?U=<?php echo $row['title']; ?> " class="list-group-item menu"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a>
           <?php } ?>
</div> 

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a.menu').click(function(){
        $('a.menu').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
         });
       });
</script>
```

Here I have used bootstrap 3.0 so in this link I have used css class active..May anybody give me a solution to solve this problem ?

Comment: preventDefault action for starters....then wrap everything in a document.ready or some such

Comment: I have used document.ready but there is same result.Here I have used global scope GET, Have there any problem for GET ?

Comment: You need to use `on('click')` . Event delegation for dynamically created `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as you are appending elements dynamically.

```
 $(document).on('click','a.menu',function(){
        $('a.menu').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
 });
```

Comment: same result after loading the page it is not working.Active class stay after click to load time, after loading page it made disappear.